# Allow {} in regex url domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex, which process a domain.

https://regexr.com/5slqa

```
/(?!-)(?!\.)(?!.*?\.\.)(?![a-zA-Z]+\-\.[a-zA-Z]+)(?![a-zA-Z]+\+[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)(?![a-zA-Z\#]+\/[a-zA-Z\-]+)(?![0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9@%._~#?={}]+-*[a-zA-Z0-9@%._~#=;]+)+.(?!-)[a-z]{2,24}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&#//=:$\[\]]*)$/
```

What I need to do is to allow the {} in the regex and satisfy the example below.

Valid example:

```
http://www.example.com/{firstname}_{lastname}
```

Invalid example:

```
http://www.example.com/{name{age}}
```

Comment: I doubt this regex is safe to use, it has an unescaped `.`  with a redundant `(?!-)` right after, and the last character class contains a `//`, which hints at the fact that the person who wrote the pattern does not quite get the purpose of a character class. Moreover, the pattern is anchored at the end, but not at the start of the string.

Comment: Assuming, its now safe. How will I apply the {} while satisfying the invalid domain of ```{name{age}}```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with the current regex, you can just replace

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&#//=:$\[\]]*
```

with

```
(?:\{[^{}]*}|[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&#\/=:$\[\]])*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UBC2Ao/1). Note the `//` typo is fixed by replacing the text with `\/`.

`(?:\{[^{}]*}|[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&#\/=:$\[\]])*` means

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\{` - a `{`
  - `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
  - `}` - a `}` char
- `|` - or

  - `[-a-zA-Z0-9@%_+.~?&#\/=:$\[\]]` - one of the sepcified (groups of) chars
- `)*` - end of the group, repeat zero or more times.